# SQL WHERE EXISTS is masking errors in Subquery

Tags: sql, runtime-error, exists

I am running a query to update a flag in a table that relies on checking that values exist in a subquery, but when the subquery gets an error (divide by zero), the `EXISTS` statement just sees it as a returned row and carries on with the update.

e.g.

```
Update xxxx
Set Flagfield=1 
FROM xxxx
WHERE
EXISTS (
Select * FROM yyyy Inner join xxxx on xxx.ID = yyyy.id
WHERE yyyy.int1 / yyyy.int2 > 1)
```

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour and can it be anticipated?

Comment: Seems that `yyyy.int2` equals zero

Comment: Why did you do a division, isn't this `WHERE yyyy.int1 > yyyy.int2` enough?

Comment: You really have `xxxx` table twice in the SQL update?

Comment: add AND yyyy.int2 <> 0 to the WHERE statement

Comment: @forpas, not for `-4 / -1` because `-4 / -1 equals 4 that is > 1` but `-4 is not > than -1`.

Comment: @daniherrera then `WHERE abs(yyyy.int1) > abs(yyyy.int2)`

Comment: @forpas, nop, because abs(-5) > abs(1) but   -5 / 1 is not > 1. LOL.

Comment: I'm getting the divide by 0 error on my tests, please tag your DBMS and add full verifiable example. Also be careful with your table alias, you are referencing table `xxxx` twice and without alias.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your UPDATE is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Do you not need something to correlate your outer query with your exists query? You'll update all xxxx if just one of the rows fulfil your exists?

Comment: `yyyy.int1 / yyyy.int2 > 1` can be written as `yyyy.int1 > yyyy.int2` to avoid division by zero issues

Comment: Use different table aliases for the two xxxx instances, and things will happen!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can try the below code, just add the check for int2 in the where statement.

```
Update xxxx
Set Flagfield=1 
FROM xxxx
WHERE
EXISTS (
Select * FROM yyyy Inner join xxxx on xxx.ID = yyyy.id
WHERE (yyyy.int2 IS NOT NULL AND yyyy.int2 <> 0) AND (yyyy.int1 / yyyy.int2 > 1))
```